Pass variable from setenv.sh to tomcat application xml file
I am trying to pass a env variable that is set in setenv.sh script to an application property file in .XML, with no luck
Something like this:
(setenv.sh)
export DB_PASSWORD=my_secure_password

application.xml file:
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydb"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="dbuser"
              password="${DB_PASSWORD}"

But when tomcat starts this component fails as it cannot get the password. Can you please tell me how to pass this variable into XML property file here?

Answering my own question
Adding below line into catalina.properties file helped,
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource  (Tomcat 9)
